# datamodeling with cassandram nosql

Tags: nosql, cassandra, data-modeling, key-value

Im trying to make a datamodel for a little game im making but i have no experience with nosql database models yet.

here is the idea:

there is a village, the village belongs to a user, and a user can have multiple villages. a village cannot have multiple owners.

any suggetions/links on a good way to work this out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

User
       [Village ...]

From what you have said, a simple composite structure with an array of villages in user will work.